# 'module' object has no attribute 'GeoSQLCompiler'

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am new to geodjango. I am using django-1.4.5 and my database settings,

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2", # Add "postgresql_psycopg2", "postgresql", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "NAME": "mydb",                       # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "USER": "postgres",                             # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "test",                         # Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "localhost",                             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",                             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

And i got the error `'module' object has no attribute 'GeoSQLCompiler'`
Please solve my problem.

Comment: do you have `django.contrib.gis` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: yes karthikr I have added the django.contrib.gis in my app

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

with

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

Comment: I have solved my problem. But you gave the right answer. I will accept your answer.